# Solve non-linear pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

so i wonder the next thing : if i consider a pde like heat equation Fourier transform works very well. Now, if i consider this equation :

$\frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial t}-k(u(t,x))\frac{\partial^2 u(t,x)}{\partial x^2} = 0$

We see Fourier transform can't help us because of the non-linear term. That's why i would like what transform is the best, for instance Laplace transform ? I think no because in Laplace space the product does not become the convolution whereas with Fourier Transform it is. So what do you think about that ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Transform methods work mainly for linear equations. For some very special (so-called “completely integrable”) nonlinear PDEs there is something called the Inverse Scattering Transform, but that's not applicable here, except maybe for some particular choice of the function $k$.

Comment: In general there will be no general method to solve this nonlinear heat equation. Fourier / Laplace Transforms only works for linear ODEs/PDEs. You might be lucky if you find a variable transformation, which transforms your PDE into a linear PDE.